# PHP DOMDocument HTMLエンティティ化

Tags: php, html, dom

下記のコードで日本語部分がエンティティ化されてしまいます。

`$newdoc->importNode($el, true)` で発生しているようなのですが、
理由と対策を教えてください。

```php
$orgdoc = new DOMDocument;
$orgdoc->loadXML("<old><span>あいうえお1</span><span>あいうえお2<span>あいうえお3</span></span></old>");
$node = $orgdoc->getElementsByTagName("old")->item(0);

$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$newdoc->loadXML("<new></new>");

foreach($node->childNodes as $el){
  $el = $newdoc->importNode($el, true);
  $newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($el);
}

echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
```

### 実行結果

```html
<new><span>&#12354;&#12356;&#12358;&#12360;&#12362;1</span><span>&#12354;&#12356;&#12358;&#12360;&#12362;2<span>&#12354;&#12356;&#12358;&#12360;&#12362;3</span></span></new>
```

### 試したこと

下記を追加してみましたが、改善しませんでした。

```php
$orgdoc->substituteEntities = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、対策については `saveHTML()` ではなく `saveXML()` を使います。単に `saveXML()` とすると XML Declaration も表示されてしまいますので `documentElement` を指定しています。

```php
echo $newdoc->saveXML($newdoc->documentElement);
```

`saveHTML()` を使いたい場合は HTML entity を UTF-8 へ変換します。

```php
echo mb_convert_encoding($newdoc->saveHTML(), 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

理由に関してですが、`saveHTML()` の場合、HTML ドキュメントのヘッダ部にある文字エンコーディングの指定を参照しているからです。

```php
$newdoc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>'."<p></p>");
            :

echo $newdoc->saveHTML();

// 出力結果
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body><p></p></body><span>あいうえお1</span><span>あいうえお2<span>あいうえお3</span></span></html>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。よく理解できました。